# Grails - cross controller code, execute on every request

Tags: grails, grails-controller

Is there a way of executing some piece of code before any controller action gets called?

I need to set a session variable based on the value of a get parameter, without taking into account which controller gets called.

Of course, once this processing is done, the request needs to follow its normal way to the corresponding controller/action.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like you want to use a [filter](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/single.html#6.6%20Filters).

e.g. *grails-app/conf/MyFilter.groovy*

```
class MyFilter {
    def filters = {
        extractSomething(controller: '*', action: '*') {
            before = {
                session.setAttribute('foo', params['paramName'])
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

filters are good if used with multiple or all controllers but could get expensive.
you may also try interceptors:

```
def beforeInterceptor = {
       session.setAttribute('foo', params['paramName'])
}
```

http://www.grails.org/Controllers+-+Interceptors