# Grails session object property is not being set during integration test

Tags: session, grails, spock

I'm trying to test a filter in Grails 2.2.1 that stores a value in the global `session` object anytime somebody hits any URL in my application.  Here's what I came up with, thanks to [this fine post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5421815/grails-cross-controller-code-execute-on-every-request):

```
package drummer

class SessionExpirationFilters {

    def filters = {
        all(controller: '*', action: '*') {
            before = {
                session.foo = 'bar'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm able to see that the filter works by outputting `session.foo` in a controller method, but the integration test fails:

```
package drummer

import grails.plugin.spock.IntegrationSpec

class QuestionControllerIntegrationSpec extends IntegrationSpec {

    def 'filter sets session foo to bar'() {
        given:
        def controller = new QuestionController()

        when:
        controller.list()

        then:
        assert 'bar' == controller.session.foo // fails, session.foo is null
    }
}
```

So why isn't the 'foo' session object property set in the integration test?

Comment: Here's someones disccusion of that:https://www.evernote.com/shard/s209/sh/e2d21b27-2f4a-409a-891b-400e71a3236a/4b2dda3166be76a67bc070bffd49f5d3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it isn't invoked is because filters are NOT automatically run in controller tests.  If your filter is in a service/util, you can write separate tests for that.

Luke Daley wrote a blog post on creating integration tests for [filters](http://ldaley.com/post/392153102/integration-testing-grails-filters) here if you want to test your filters directly:

```
import grails.util.GrailsWebUtil

class MyFilterTests extends GroovyTestCase {
    def filterInterceptor
    def grailsApplication
    def grailsWebRequest

    def request(Map params, controllerName, actionName) {
        grailsWebRequest = GrailsWebUtil.bindMockWebRequest(grailsApplication.mainContext)
        grailsWebRequest.params.putAll(params)
        grailsWebRequest.controllerName = controllerName
        grailsWebRequest.actionName = actionName
        filterInterceptor.preHandle(grailsWebRequest.request, grailsWebRequest.response, null)
    }

    def getResponse() {
        grailsWebRequest.currentResponse
    }

    def testFilterRedirects() {
        def result = request("home", "index", someParameter: "2")
        assertFalse result
        assertTrue response.redirectedUrl.endsWith(/* something */)
    }    
}
```